# Facebook Graph API commenting on mentions thorws OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using /user/mentions edge to create comment on Instagram post my Instagram Business User was mentioned, like this: **POST: user_id/mentions?media_id=media_id&message=some_message**.

The documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/mentions says that I need instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments and one of manage_pages, ads_management, business_management permissions.

I have following permissions: instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments and manage_pages, but still getting "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action".

Do I still need all permissions or something is wrong with my request?

Comment: are you sure you are sending a correct POST request? please add the relevant code or a graph api explorer link.

Comment: here is link to graph api explorer screenshot https://prnt.sc/ndl4sw and token info http://prntscr.com/ndl7jo

Comment: please add the screenshot to your question, never add important information in comments. anyway, i have created an answer, could be it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is a POST request, but you send the parameters in the URL. Click on "Add a Field" to add POST variables instead.

If that does not solve it, then i assume it´s a review thing. The error message usually means that you need to get whitelisted, or reviewed.

Also, try adding the following permissions: `ads_management, manage_pages, business_management`. And if you want to reply to a comment that includes the mention tag, you need to add the `comment_id` to.

Comment: I've tried both cases, the same result: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"